# How to create two tables migration using php artisan command for Laravel Project?

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

I am using composer for migrating two tables like this:

```
php artisan make:migration create_two_tables --create="projects","tasks"
```

Its creating the file in `database->migration` folder.

but while migrating using

```
php artisan migrate
```

its creating only table in database like this:

```
'projects,tasks'
```

as one table.

I want only one file and only one command like what I do in the top for migrating two tables in db.

Is there any possibility to get this?

Note: My superior ordered me to not change the database migration file at any cost...

Can anyone help me out here...

Answer (score 3):

The `make:migration` command is just to create a new migration file from a template. To actually define the migration you normally have to edit that file. So in your case you would do this:

```
php artisan make:migration create_two_tables --create="projects"
```

Then open the `***_create_two_tables.php` migration file and add the second table:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projects', function(Blueprint $table)
    {

    });

    Schema::create('tasks', function(Blueprint $table)
    {

    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('projects');
    Schema::drop('tasks');
}
```

Usually you also want to add actual columns to your tables. And that you do inside the `Schema::create` closure:

```
Schema::create('projects', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    // and so on
});
```

[Read more about creating tables with the Schema Builder here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema)

Comment: I did this already, and I want through command prompt to create this tables, Is there any possibility like that

Comment: Not without your own command. But it is it that hard to open a file and copy paste + change the table name?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just create two tables through artisan and not add any columns to those tables you can create two migrations. Create one for each table.  When you run

```
 php artisan make:migration create_projects_table --create=projects    
 php artisan make:migration create_tasks_table --create=tasks
 php artisan migrate
```

it will execute both migrations and create both tables for you.